# Xamarin iOS get status back of a phone call

Tags: xamarin.ios, openurl

Is there a way to get the call status back after a call is made from an app. I am using following to make a call

```
  NSUrl url = new NSUrl("tel://" + phoneStr);
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

It shows a pop up with "Cancel" and "Call" button. If user cancels it stays back in the app, if user clicks call it initiates a call. I would like to get the click action if user made a call or canceled it.
Is there a way to get that status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 10+ We can use `CXCallObserver` to capture the event when user make a phone call like:

```
//Make sure both CXCallObserver and ObserverDelegate a strong reference
private CXCallObserver callObserver;
private MyCallObserverDelegate myCallDelegate;

callObserver = new CXCallObserver();
myCallDelegate = new MyCallObserverDelegate();
callObserver.SetDelegate(myCallDelegate, null);
```

Implement the delegate for `CXCallObserver`:

```
public class MyCallObserverDelegate : CXCallObserverDelegate
{
    public override void CallChanged(CXCallObserver callObserver, CXCall call)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(call.Outgoing);
        Console.WriteLine(call.HasConnected);
        Console.WriteLine(call.OnHold);
        Console.WriteLine(call.HasEnded);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, it will not fire when user click cancel.

After user click the button(cancel or call), the app will fire `DidBecomeActiveNotification`, so I recommend you create a delay method when `DidBecomeActiveNotification` fires. Then we can detect which button user clicks:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidBecomeActiveNotification, async (notification) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    detectCalling();
});
```

In early time we can define a field `bool isDialing = false`, if `CallChanged()` fires set it true. At last we can detect the field in `detectCalling();`.

Comment: Are you sure if it works with iOS 11. Cellular call states are deprecated in iOS 11.

Comment: @User382 I’ve tested it on iOS 11.2.2, it works fine.

Comment: It works but the call.CallState == "CTCallStateDialing" is deprecated. Please see the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/core_telephony_constants

Comment: @User382 I have updated my answer, modified `CTCallStateDialing` to `CXCallObserver`.