# How to resize view when in-call status bar appears in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, statusbar, in-call

In my xamarin application i need to resize view when in-call status bar is present. As per xamarin documents for iOS, I have tried using ObserveWillChangeStatusBarFrame notification (WillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification is deprecated in Xamarin iOS) which never fires on in-call status bar appearance.

No further documentation is available on this topic.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you want to receive the notification when user has a call in? If so you can try `CXCallObserver`, refer to my thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315072/8354952) for more details.